# Difference between the limit of function and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

What's the difference between two concepts,  1. limit of function and 2. continuous function?
I looked at their definitions in the textbook written by Rudin and
it's so hard to differentiate between them.

They look similar to me.

[Edited]
 **I can't find the difference between two definition. If they are the same, it means that a function is continous if and only if every point is a limit point. But this is not true. So I want to know what makes a difference between a point being a limit of function and function being itself continuous**

Images of Definitions

[image]

[image]

Comment: @CameronBuie I have no idea why this is a duplicate of that question. I just read the question: Definition of continuity at a point, and it was asking about dropping the condition 0<… in dX(x,p)<δ.

Comment: The other question asked about the difference between Rudin's definitions of function limit and continuity at a point, too. Were you curious about something else, instead? If so, please elaborate in your post, and we'll be glad to answer.

Comment: @CameronBuie My question is that I can't find the difference between two definition. If they are the same, it means that a function is continous if and only if every point is a limit point. But this is not true. So I want to know what makes a difference between a point being a limit of function and function being itself continuous

Comment: Could you write the two definitions?
I don't have the Rudin's book at hand.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/455296/28900) would seem to be related, then, even though it isn't about Rudin's definitions, specifically. I second Makoto's request to add the definitions in question to your post. Also, you should explain **in your post** (since not everyone reads the comments) what is troubling you about the definitions.

Comment: @MakotoKato I've attached the image of two definitions!

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm sorry that nobody can answer your question anymore because it was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Now that you've posted your definitions, it's even clearer that your post is indeed a duplicate of the other. The other user simply noticed the only difference between the definitions of function limit and continuity at a point. (Note the difference between continuity at a point and being a continuous function. Also, did you compare with the remark after definition 4.1?) Rudin's definition does *not* imply that every point of the domain is a limit point, as he proceeds to explain after Definition 4.5 ("It should be noted....")

Comment: @Makoto: You have enough reputation that you can always vote to reopen. (Also, you can request reopening at the appropriate [meta page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424/28900), if you like.)

Comment: While the definition $4.1$ does not require that $f(x)$ is defined at $p$,
the definition $4.5$ requires that $f(x)$ is defined at $p$.
Moreover the definition $4.5$ requires that $lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = f(p)$.

Answer (score 3):

The limit (if it exists) is the number the function approaches. In precise terms $L$ is the limit of $f$ at $a$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$, so that for every $x$, $0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. When the function is *continuous* at $a$, the number it approaches at $a$ is $f(a)$. So in the definition above, $L$ is replaced by $f(a)$. You can also change the first part to $|x - a| < \delta$ since the statement is clearly true for $x = a$ also. That's why the definitions look so similar.

In the book, notice that for limits, it uses a general variable $q \in Y$ but for continuity, it is replaced with $f(p)$.