# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ exist? A comparison with the $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ can be easily evaluated  by simplification:
$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. At this point, the right-hand limit can be taken: $\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=+\infty$, but left-hand limit $\lim_{x\to 0-} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ can not be evaluated as the function is not defined for $x < 0$. So my question now is: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = +\infty$ or should I say it does not exist? My doubt comes from the fact that $\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{x}=0$, as explained in this  ([answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637280/limit-of-sqrt-x-as-x-approaches-0)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order that $\sqrt x$ is defined you have to take the domain as $[0,\infty)$ and so you can only talk about the right-hand limit. The required limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: So should I say that both $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ only exit for the restricted domain $[0, \infty]$? I was convinced (link answer in the question) that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}=0$ because we can not evaluate the function for $x<0$, then we can not apply the left and right-hand theorem.

Comment: The first sentence is correct it infinite limits are allowed. If you want to consider only finite limits  then none of the limits exist.

Comment: What do you mean by taking the domain as $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0, \infty)$ for that matter)? The function $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is (if we're talking real analysis) only defined for $x > 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can think of:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
and so:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit, in order to exist, must be two-sided. As $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ DNE, it follows that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ DNE. (However, the RHL is equal to $\infty$ as Henry Lee points out.)

Similarly, $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}$ DNE because the LHL does not exit; however, the RHL is equal to $0$.

Comment: “The limit, in order to exist, must be two-sided”: what world authority has so decreed?

Comment: LHL and RHL must exist and be equal; otherwise the limit as we define it does not exist; that is, a limit is ``two-sided.''

Comment: Who is “we”? I'm surely not among them. If a function $f$ is defined on a set $D$ and $c$ is a limit point of $D$, then *I* (and am not the only one) say that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ if (and only if) for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ with the following property: for every $x\in D$, if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. An obvious consequence of this definition is that $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{x}=0$.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't know what Calculus book you are teaching from, but the idea of the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition you allude to means that we can get arbitrarily close to $0$ (in the example you cite) from both sides, As this is impossible in the case of $f(x) = \sqrt{x},$ the RHL exists and is equal to $0$. The LHL does not exist; and therefore, the limit as $we$ know it by the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition does not exist. It is perhaps because of arguments like the one that you are trying to make that  this definition of limit took over two thousand years to get to us.

Comment: Did you read carefully, including the condition $x\in D$? Again, your *we* does not include me and many other people.

Comment: I never implied it did; but it does include authors from widely accepted Calculus textbooks, including the ones I have often had access to.

Comment: OK, then the function $\sqrt{x}$ is not continuous at zero, is it?

Comment: I'm glad you  ask that. The function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous over $(0, \infty)$ and continuous from the right at $0$. I don't mean to be presumptuous, but based on what you have previously argued, you would have to say it is continuous at $0$ and thus continuous over $[0, \infty]$. But without the distinction that I have tried to bear witness to, why do such notions as right-hand and left-hand limits, as well as the notions of continuity from the right and continuity from the left appear in textbooks? Certainly, they are there for reasons that pertain to our discussion.

Comment: @mlchristians: Surely **every** mathematician agrees that the (real) square root function is continuous, which includes it being continuous at the point $x=0$. If the function is defined for $x>0$ and undefined for $x<0$, then (as egreg is correctly trying to point out to you) the limit as $x \to 0$ is **the same thing** as the right-hand limit as $x \to 0^+$. See the similar recent discussion here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279554/what-is-the-point-0-0-of-sqrtx-called