# Single point function is not a continuous function according to the intermediate value theorem

Tags: continuity

According to the intermediate value theorem, we can infer that a single point function, for example $f(x) = \sqrt x + \sqrt(-x)$, which has a range of only $0$ and a domain of only $0$ is not a continuous function. Is my conclusion right or there is actually exception when it is continuous? or outside of the calculus realm of thinking single point function CAN BE continuous?

Comment: What (precise) definition are you using? See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455296/can-a-function-with-just-one-point-in-its-domain-be-continuous.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem does not imply that  $f(x) = \sqrt x+\sqrt{-x}$ is not continuous, since it states that $f$ takes all values between $f(0) = 0$ and... $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: No, we certainly cannot infer what you claim from the IVT. Why not? Nobody can say what the error in your reasoning is since you don't explain _how_ you think IVT implies this...

Answer (score 1):

Although there are similar duplicates here a quick reasoning:

- You consider a real-valued function with domain $D = \{0\}$, so you can use the limit definition of continuity:
  $$f \mbox{ is continuous at } x_0 = 0 $$
  $$\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = f(0) \mbox{ for all sequences } \{x_n\}_{n \in D}\subset D \mbox{ with } \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$$
- The only possible sequence converging to $0$ in the domain $\{0\}$ is the constant sequence $x_n = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = f(0) = 0$$
  So, $f$ is contiuous.